# flask function call as part of variable

Tags: python, flask

I am building a blog using flask and sqlalchemy on PythonAnywhere. I have a MySQL table called posts that contains fields title and text (among others). My flask page template cycles through entries in the posts table and does this to print out the text of each post

```
{{ post.text | safe }}
```

This is great because it allows me to include HTML formatting in each post.

What I want to do is call functions from in a post. I have defined this function in my main python file

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def weekly_table(week):
        query = ThisSeason.query.filter_by(week=week)
        df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, con=db.engine)
        df = df.drop('id',1)
        df = df.set_index('teamid')
        return df.to_html(classes="pure-table")
    return dict(weekly_table=weekly_table)
```

When I call this function in my template using

```
{{ weekly_table(1) | safe }}
```

it prints out exactly what I want, a formatted HTML table of the dataframe.

However, I can't figure out for the life of me how I would call weekly_table() in one of my posts. If I use

```
{{ weekly_table(1) | safe }}
```

it prints the code rather than the desired table, presumably because it is being called as part of

```
{{ post.text | safe }}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: yes if someone else can also post to it (eg: if you have no authentication system), and also if you would worried about privilege escalation (if they find a way to login to your website and post, then they would be able to wipe all your code and data because of this security hole)